# How can i use parameterization in Jenkins freestyle jobs?

Tags: jenkins

I have about 20 jobs that do almost the same thing except for a few tasks. Each job gets the same files from repository , so what i am looking at doing is getting the repository only once and having some checkbox that the user selects and if it is a certain check box then it does certain tasks .

How can i do this using Freestyle Jobs in Jenkins ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **choice param in jenkins** as given in this image --> [choice param in jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roj7L.png)

And controls what to do in **jenkins build step** using shell if conditions as given in this image --> [build step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6r1Z.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).